# A referential integrity constraint violation occurred. When Updating EF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

I can't seem to be able to update a model with foreignKey constraint getting this error :

> Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation
>   occurred: The property value(s) of 'Country.Id' on one end of a
>   relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Setting.CountryId'
>   on the other end.

**Setting Model**

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Setting : BaseModel
    {

        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string Slogan { get; set; }
        public byte[] Logo { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("State")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public  State State { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public  Country Country { get; set; }

        public string IsDefault { get; set; }


    }
}
```

**State Model**

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class State :BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Country Model**

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Country : BaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Repository to Get and Update Setting

```
public Setting GetSetting()
{
    try
    {
        return _db.Settings.Include("Country").Include("State").First();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}

public Setting UpdateSetting(Setting setting)
{
    try
    {
        _db.Settings.Attach(setting);
        _db.Entry(setting).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return setting;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

}
```

Note I am Using WCF Proxy

Button Click Event

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt16(cmbState.EditValue).ToString());
    //return;

    if (dxValidationProvider1.Validate())
    {
        if (picLogo.Image == null)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Upload Logo");
        }
        else
        {
            var setting = proxy.GetSetting();
            //MessageBox.Show(cmbState.EditValue.ToString()); return;

            setting.HotelName = txtHotelName.Text;
            setting.Address = txtAddress.Text;
            setting.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            setting.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
            setting.Website = txtWebsite.Text;
            setting.Slogan = txtSlogan.Text;
            setting.City = txtCity.Text;

            setting.CountryId = Convert.ToInt16(cmbCounty.EditValue);

            setting.StateId = Convert.ToInt16(cmbState.EditValue));

            setting.Logo = picLogo.Image.ToByteArray();

            var s = proxy.UpdateSetting(setting);

            MessageBox.Show(@"Updated");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the required fields");
    }
}
```

Comment: `CountryId` is `Int32`, but you're converting `cmbCountry.EditValue` to `Int16` and trying to assign it to `CountryId`. They're different types.

Comment: I tried that getting the same error

Comment: I assume that the property `Id` in `BaseModel` is `int` or `Int32`?

Comment: the id in the BaseModel is int

Comment: First, you seem to be using non standard (DevExpress) controls. Second, it's unclear what is in `EditValue` property of your combo boxes.

Comment: I manually typed the StateId = 1 and CountryID = 2 the both exist in the both corresponding tables but still get the same error

Comment: Ok.  Not hundred percent sure if that's the issue, but since your `GetSetting` method is returning navigation properties, and you are modifying the FK properties, when you send the object back they will be out of sync. Try setting them to `null` before calling `proxy.UpdateSettings` and see if the problem persists, i.e. `setting.Country = null; setting.State = null; var s = proxy.UpdateSetting(setting);`

Comment: the same error: Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Country.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Setting.CountryId' on the other end.

Comment: As a side note I would strongly recommend you persist country [ISO codes (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 or ISO 3166-1 alpha-2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) instead of a country lookup table. It is less maintenance and easier to use in your code. You can then also use libraries (or web end points) to get localized country names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the Include statment from the GetSetting function and everything updated. This solved my problem

```
public Setting GetSetting()
{
    try
    {
        return _db.Settings.First();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```